# Laravel Eloquent: Loads only last entry

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing some issues with a query.

The result for this

```
public function index()
{
    $subscribers = Subscriber::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('backend.newsletter.contacts.index')->withSubscribers($subscribers);
}
```

is only the last entry. My assumption with get() is that I get all entries that match my where clause?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it should return all the matching entries. Are you sure that there are more than one matching row in your database?

Comment: Is there more than one entry for the current user?

Comment: Yes. I've updated my question with a screenshot

Comment: How are you seeing that there's only 1 entry? var_dump/print_r, or when outputting to the screen? Can you show that code?

Comment: Oh sorry guys, such a stupid mistake! I've put @endforeach in the wrong place